# Asp net core 2.2, updating usename not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity

I want my user to be able to change his username so i made this:

```
        <form asp-action="UpdateUserProfile" asp-controller="Account" method="post">

            <div class="account-details-item">
                <h2 class="center-text text-left account-details-item-title">UserName:</h2>
                <input name="username" id="username-text" readonly="readonly" class="center-text account-details-item-value" asp-for="User.UserName" value=@Model.User.UserName>
                <a id="btn-username" class="account-details-item-btn" >Edit</a>
            </div>
            <div class="account-details-item">
                <h2 class="center-text text-left account-details-item-title">Email:</h2>
                <input name="email" readonly="readonly" id="email-text" class="center-text account-details-item-value email" asp-for="User.Email" value=@Model.User.Email />
                <a id="btn-email" class="account-details-item-btn" >Edit</a>
            </div>
            <div class="account-details-item">
                <h2 class="center-text text-left account-details-item-title">Phone number:</h2>
                <input name="phonenumber" readonly="readonly" id="phone-text" class="center-text account-details-item-value" asp-for="User.PhoneNumber" value=@Model.User.PhoneNumber>
                <a id="btn-phone" class="account-details-item-btn" >Edit</a>
            </div>
            <div class="btns-container">
                <div class="btn-item"><a asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Cart" asp-route-id=@Model.User.CartId>Go To Cart</a></div>
                <div id="save-btn" class="btn-item"><button type="submit">Save Changes</button></div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

And in **AccountController:**

```
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult UpdateUserProfile()
        {
            var username = Request.Form["username"];
            var phonenumber = Request.Form["phonenumber"];
            var email = Request.Form["email"];
            var user = _userService.GetUser(User);



            if(`enter code here`IsUsernameDiffrent(username))
            {
                _userService.UpdateUsername(User, username);

                _userManager.UpdateAsync(user.Result);
            }
            else if(IsEmailDiffrent(email))
            {
                _userService.UpdateEmail(User, email);
                _userManager.UpdateAsync(user.Result);

            }
            else if (IsPhoneNumberDiffrent(phonenumber))
            {
                _userService.UpdatePhoneNumber(User, phonenumber);
                _userManager.UpdateAsync(user.Result);

            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

And in **Service Class:**

```
   public async void UpdateUsername(ClaimsPrincipal user, string newUsername)
        {
            var currentUser = await GetUser(user);

            currentUser.UserName = newUsername;

            _dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }
```

The issue is that if user change his username he still have to login with the old one,
changes are made in database but whenever i try to login with new username it says "**Invalid login attempt**"

Comment: If you've confirmed the new username is being passed correctly and being written to the database, then it doesn't appear to be an issue with the code you've posted.  I'd debug upon login with new username and see where in the database it is checking for authentication to see why the new username fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an **Update User Action** in my project and it does work in mine, and its little different from yours, but you can try to change it like that:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateUserProfile()
{
     var user = _userService.GetUser(User);

     if (user == null)
     {
         return StatusCode(404);
     }

     var username = Request.Form["username"];

     if(IsUsernameDifferent(username))
     {
         user.UserName = username;   

         var result = await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);

         if (result.Succeeded)
         {
            return RedirectToAction("Action", "Controller");
         }

         return View();
     }
     return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel that more code must be seen to analyze the issue. But, make sure you are using transaction scope in your services when you are making changes to the data in the database like update or delete.

Using this technique will ensure that the code is consistent. Changes to the database will not happen unless everything inside the scope is successful. For example, if you are updating and then deleting, what if while deleting an error occurs. Then your data will be updated in the database but not deleted. This is to make sure that both happens successfully or nothing happens at all.

Refer this link.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/transactions